# find() method does not appear to work as expected

Tags: xpath, geb

I have been using the find() method is order to find relative xpaths, but it is not working like I thought it would, and I am wondering if i am misunderstanding how it is meant to work

On the page I am testing I have 2 `thead` elements. one is for small screens while the other is for large screens.

Assume each `thead` has child `<tr>` and 4 `<th>` grandchildren

assume I have Navigator element `myElement` which is pointing to only 1 of the theads and not the other (single element here) if I want all of the `<th>`s under `myElement` specifically, I figured I could say:

```
myElement.find(By.xpath("//th"))
```

What I get as a return appears to be both sets of `<th`>s from both `thead`s even though I expect to see only the set relative to `myElement`.

Am I misunderstanding .find()'s use case, or do I have another issue?

(no need to try and figure out what that issue is. I simply want to assert i am using .find() correctly.)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `.//th`? I thought `//th` would always start at the root.

Comment: @melpomene From [wc3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) `// - Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are` `/ - Selects from the root node`

Comment: when making xpaths you can put `//` in the middle like so: `//thead//th` that will only return `th`s that are under a `thead` I assumed the find worked in a similar way. If you look at this doc: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-elements-when-i-already-have-a-dom-element/ it appears thats how it should work, but I am not sure it is working that way.

Comment: @BladeMight From the actual [XPath spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-path-expressions): "A path expression that starts with `/` or `//` selects nodes starting from the root of the tree containing the context item; it is often referred to as an absolute path expression."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switching `//th` to `.//th` did the trick for me. Credit goes to melpomene though